# Convert varchar to decimal and compare values in a query

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to compare in a query between decimal values in varchar columns.
The comparison should be if maximum age is highest than the minimum age * 10 for each groupid

for example (the age column is varchar):

```
ID | Name | Age  | GroupID
--------------------------
1  | AAA  | 10.1 | 1
2  | BBB  | 11   | 1
3  | CCC  | 31.2 | 1
4  | DDD  | 30.4 | 2
```

This is what I've tried to do after searching for a solution

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Groups g
JOIN People p1 ON p1.GroupID = g.ID
JOIN People p2 ON p2.GroupID = g.ID
WHERE CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),ISNULL(p1.Age,0)) > (CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2),ISNULL(p2.Age,0)) * 10)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Age is really a varchar in your db ? So first think would be to change that !

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the columns types..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when isnumeric(Age) = 1 then cast(Age as float) end) over
                 (partition by groupID) as minage
      from table t
     ) t
where age > 10 * minage;
```

The `case` statement helps prevent errors in the event that age's are not numeric.  Also, I figure `float` is a good enough data type for the age, although you can also use `decimal`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! But I get "[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Comment: This syntax looks correct to me.  Can you edit your question with the structure of the tables?  It looks like the age is stored in a separate table from the other columns.